# How to get Bloomberg API and how to use it in Rblpapi package

Tags: r, api, bloomberg

I'm new to Rblpapi package in R and I'm trying to figure out how it works. In the documentation it is written, that to connect to Bloomberg API I need to type

**blpConnect()**

Shouldn't I use special API number for that? How can I get it? I'm a student at uni and we have several Bloomberg terminals. I tried to contact Bloomberg Help Desk but it seems they don't know what is Bloomberg API either.

Please explain to me how to get Bloomberg API and where to insert it to use Rblpapi package.